# Character model keeps disappearing in Unreal 5.2

Tags: model, unreal

I updated my unreal engine to 5.2, and took my file with it. I was working on this project when this happened. My character suddenly disappears whenever I look at specific angles. HELP! I am very new and this is my first project.[Here's what's happening](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hLogCQo3tX2_JCYanEmFu0itm564XMip/view?usp=sharing)

I tried to edit the Bounds scale in the viewport, tried reimporting all of my assets, tried reanimating the file, recoding it, nothing worked.

Comment: check your physics asset, and ensure the entire mesh is encapsulated in sphere or boxes